Мультирегиональность Аспро
Установлено мультирегиональность на одном домене https://mysite.ru/arzamas/ при переходе выводит 404 кто сталкивался с таким подскажите куда копать?

В настройках сайта каталог выставлен?

Наверно надо создать страницу, отвечающую за вывод региональных подразделений, например mysite.ru/regions. И в настройках инфоблока подразделений установить URL страницы раздела и URL страницы детального просмотра. Например: /regions/#SECTION_CODE#/ и /regions/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEENT_CODE#/
